# ElasticSearch analyzer for German language

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a German word with umlaut, lets say it is "läuft". My target is to create an analyzer that produces three tokens at the end: "läuft", "laeuft" and "lauft".

I have tried different combinations with *icu_normalizer*, *asciifolding* and *snowball for German2* filters but no results. The best result I've got from *asciifolding* token filter that emits two out of three required tokens: "läuft" and "lauft".

So, basically, I need to create some kind of custom *asciifolding* filter for German language that will allow to emit additional variations for words with umlauts.

My configuration for *asciifolding* and *snowball* filters are the following:

```
"ascii2": {
              "type": "asciifolding",
              "preserve_original": "true"
            },

"snow-german2": {
              "type": "snowball",
              "language": "German2"
            },
```

I would be really appreciated for your help!

Comment: [This thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Folding-German-characters-like-umlauts-td2176078.html) might help, and if not, we'll figure out something ;)

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/issues/2) which seems related.

Comment: Thank you! I've read this thread already. Author uses customized snowball-German2 filter (same like I did) but it does not work at the moment. I think his patch was removed from snowball source code.

Comment: *combo* analyzer should be fine. I can combine asciifolding with custom replace filter to get all three possible forms. Thx a lot!

Comment: BTW, even on official *combo* page (https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/) you can see that "Köln" was not correctly expanded. Only two forms were emitted: original "Köln" and "Koln" but "Koeln" is missing.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: ... that "Köln" was not correctly expanded >>by snowball German2 filter<<